# is tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler equal with tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw in functional?

Tags: rospy, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is  tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler  equal with tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw in functional?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10582/is--tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler--equal-with-tf::createquaternionmsgfromyaw-in-functional?/) by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2011-07-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not the same. The first expects three Euler angles and will produces an arbitrary rotation in space and results in a quaternion. The second only needs one angle and will produce a rotation around the z-Axis and return a quaternion message.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on 2011-07-13**:
Thanks,  I‘m just to verify it.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-13**:
If you pass 0 for roll and pitch the results should be equivalent, although different data types.

**Comment by [gong](https://answers.ros.org/users/551/gong/) on 2011-07-13**:
so, if I just provide yaw the two methods would be the same?